# Antlr failing to match [a-z]+

Tags: antlr4

Trying to split off the first word of the input, so that `apple a type of fruit` would be split into `apple` and `a type of fruit`.

```
grammar Hello;

entry
  :  headword definition
  ;

headword
  :  HEADWORD
  ;

definition
  :  ANYTHING
  ;

HEADWORD : [a-z]+ ;
SPACE   : [ \t]+ -> skip ;
ANYTHING : .+;
```

Using the [Getting Started](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md#a-first-example) walkthrough:

```
C:\Code\antlr\hello>java org.antlr.v4.Tool Hello.g4
warning(131): Hello.g4:17:12: greedy block ()+ contains wildcard; the non-greedy syntax ()+? may be preferred

C:\Code\antlr\hello>javac Hello*.java

C:\Code\antlr\hello>grun Hello entry -tree

C:\Code\antlr\hello>java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig Hello entry -tree
asdf asdf
^Z
line 1:0 missing HEADWORD at 'asdf asdf\r\n'
(entry (headword <missing HEADWORD>) (definition asdf asdf\r\n))
```

Why is it failing to match HEADWORD?

Even trying to match HEADWORD directly doesn't work:

```
C:\Code\antlr\hello>grun Hello HEADWORD -tree
asdf^Z

Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

It seems to loop forever so I had to kill it with Ctrl-C.

Comment: I think this is because `ANYTHING` is capturing the whole input. Per [this](https://sodocumentation.net/antlr/topic/3271/lexer-rules-in-v4#priority-rules), it does produce the longest input match. Maybe try to change it so it matches anything that's not a space.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz, I tried matching HEADWORD directly (see my updated question). It's not looping forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ANTLR lexer rule consumes as many characters as possible. So your rule `ANYTHING : .+;` consumes the entire input, causing it to be the only token to be created. That is why `HEADWORD` is not created.

Yes, ANTLR's lexer rule are being matched top to bottom, but the top to bottom only has meaning when 2 (or more) lexer rules match the same amount of characters. Then the rule defined first "wins", but only if the (multiple) rules match the same amount of character. In your case, `ANYTHING` will (almost) always match the most characters, and will therefor be the sole token to be created.

If your input would've been just `"apple"`, then a `HEADWORD` token would be created, because both `HEADWORD` and `ANYTHING` match the input, but `HEADWORD` is defined first, so it gets precedence.

And changing `.+` to `.+?` will just cause `ANYTHING` to be never matched for your input `apple a type of fruit`. Just 5 `HEADWORD` tokens will be created.

As a rule of thumb, it is never a good idea to let a lexer rule end with `.*` or `.+` (or `.*?` or `.+?`).

Comment: Yes, and making ANYTHING non-greedy solved my problem: ANYTHING: .+?; Thanks!

Comment: @SergeySlepov you're welcome, but for your input `apple a type of fruit` and the use of `.+?` instead of `.+`, there would never be a `ANYTHING` token created. Only 5 `HEADWORD` tokens would be created.